# ¿Es posible hacer comparaciones entre grupos?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo el siguiente dataframe: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o_YP3cCiqUtLLotFNFl0k7I7OyOgRH1l/view?usp=sharing

Después he realizado un ggplot

```
   library(RColorBrewer)
   library(ggplot2)
   library(ggsignif)

plot<-ggplot(Medias_Conc, aes(fill=Kit,y=mean_conc, x=`Metodo de maceración`)) + 
   geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",width = 0.9,) +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean_conc-se_conc, ymax=mean_conc+se_conc), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9),size=0.8)+
   scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T, option = "E") +
   ggtitle("") +
   facet_wrap(~Especie) +
   theme_ipsum() +
   theme(legend.position="none") +
   xlab("")+
   theme_minimal() + 
   theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank())   +
   theme(axis.line = element_line(color = 'black',size = rel(1.5)))+
   labs(x="Método de extracción", y="Concentración (ng/μl))")+
   scale_fill_manual(values=brewer.pal(n = 3, name = "Accent"))+
   ylim(NA, 1000)
```

Obteniendo un plot como este:

[image: ggplot]

y me gustaría obtener un gráfico como este, donde existe comparaciones dentro de cada especie (en este caso en bromus, carduus y cucumis) y dentro de cada método de extracción (I, II o III) entre los diferentes tipos de kits (A,B y C)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que al ser varias gráficas juntas en una única, no obtengo lo que quiero

```
      plot+geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("A", "B")), y_position = 500,
            map_signif_level=TRUE, textsize=15, size= 0.8,annotation=c("**"))
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
       1: Computation failed in `stat_signif()`:
       valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
```

Por otro lado he probado esta opción:

```
       annotation_df <- data.frame(Especie=c("Bromus rubeus", "Stipa parviflora"),
                          y=c(500, 300), 
                          start=c("I", "I"), 
                          end=c("II", "III"),
                          label=c("**", "*"))

       plot+geom_signif(data=annotation_df,
            aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, annotations=label, y_position=y),
            textsize = 3, vjust = -0.2, manual=TRUE)
```

Dandome este error:

```
          Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : objeto 'Kit' no encontrado
          Además: Warning message:
          Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xmin, xmax, annotations, y_position
```

Me gustaría saber como arreglar este problema a la hora de añadir la significancia.¿Cuál es mi fallo?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar el nivel de  significancia entra los grupos A, B , C ,puedes asignar  manualmente cada una de las marcas donde quieres que aparezca la información utilizando el ejemplo que nos mandan y realizando sobre los A,B,C

```
#Aqui de forma manula asiganamos donde queremos que aparezca la etiqueta
 plot+ geom_signif(y_position = c(750,750), xmin = c(0.7,1.3), 
              xmax = c(1.0,1.8), annotation = c("**","**"),
              tip_length = 0)
   
 #y_position es la altura de la marca en y
 # xmin es donde inicia la marca en x
 # xmax donde acaba la marca
 #El numero de elementos del vector es cuantas marca aparecen
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es el complemento a para contestar la pregunta , si lo que deseas es agregar un nivel de significancia distinto a cada una de las facetas se tiene que hacer lo siguiente:

```
plot+ geom_signif(data=data.frame(Especie=c("Bromus rubeus","Carduus bourgeanus","Papaver rhoeas")),
              aes(y_position=c(500,500,500),
                  xmin=c(0.8,0.8,2.80),
                  xmax=c(1.2,1.2,3.2),
                  annotations=c("Test1","Test2","Test3")),manual=TRUE,inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí lo importante es que el nombre de la columna concisa con el nombre de data coincida con el nombre donde quieres agregar las marcas es decir en este caso sea Especie y que los datos internos coincidan con el nombre dela faceta donde quieres insertar la nota

Por ultimo tu data.frame tiene una particularidad que que dentro de la columna de Especies, lo que separa a la palabra no es un espacio normal es un espacio duro por si ocupa la barra para ponerlo no lo reconocerá y creara una nueva faceta en la gráfica la diferencia se puede ver aquí

```
utf8ToInt(Medias_Conc$Especie[1])
[1]  66 114 111 109 117 115 160 114 117  98 101 117 115
Medias_Conc$Especie[1]

utf8ToInt("Bromus rubeus")
[1]  66 114 111 109 117 115  32 114 117  98 101 117 115
```

El carácter de espacio en uutf-8 es 32 pero en tu base lo marca como 160 , a la vista R se ven iguales pero no los son, así que cuando crees el vector Especies dentro del data.frame que va en data usa ALT+0160, o cambia el carácter de espacio a al de espacio normal

Comment: Muchas gracias Rubén, aun así no es lo que quieró, lo que quería es que para cada gráfico existan valores de signficancia diferentes, es decir que los valores de significancia de Bromus sean diferentes a los de Stipa parviflora.

Comment: Hola Adrián realiza ya los cambios necesarios en la respuesta ahora puedes incluir anotaciones distintas en cada parte de las diferentes gráficas

Comment: Funciona correctamente, ¡gracias a los dos!

Answer (score 1):

> En primer lugar me gustaría saber como añadir otra linea horizontal
> para las tres gráficas de arriba

Entiendo que hablas de el eje `x`, en cuyo caso, puedes agregar `scales='free'`, en tu ejemplo la escala es la misma en los tres gráficos, por lo que esta opción simplemente agrega e eje horizontal que falta

```
facet_wrap(~Especie, scales='free') +
```

> me gustaría añadir la significancia entre las barras de error de los
> kits (A,B,C), el problema que al ser varias gráficas juntas en una
> única no obtengo lo que quiero

Puedes establecer los valores de forma manual:

```
geom_signif(y_position = c(500,500,500,300,300,300), 
              xmin = c(1 - 1/3, 2 -1/3, 3 -1/3, 1, 2, 3), 
              xmax = c(1, 2, 3, 1 + 1/3, 2 + 1/3, 3 + 1/3), 
              annotation = c("*","*","*","**","**","**"))+
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]